# how to check primitive data type of any value in java

Tags: java

I have a file containing list of values which may be just a string or an integer.

```
bhushan 21
kedar 20
```

When i read values in a string array i also want to perform some arithmetic operations if the data that i have is an integer or double. How do i check whether the data that i have is an integer, double or a string?
I am currently storing all values in a string array using split function and whenever i want to take average of all numbers i convert the numbers that i am sure of to integers or double and then perform arithmetic operations. I want to write a method that will tell me what exactly is the type of that value.

Comment: use regex and convert to int or convert to int and catch a numberformatexception

Comment: Try to convert it to an integer and see if it fails? Use a regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a regular expression should be the most efficient way.  Other expressions can be used to further look for floating point numbers, etc.

```
String input = "12345";
java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(".*[^0-9].*");

if( pattern.matcher(input).matches() )
    System.out.println("Its a number");
else
    System.out.println("Its not a number");
```

You can also use the `Integer.parseInt()` or `Double.parseDouble()` methods, however, they will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the input does not conform.

Comment: I get "Its not a number" for this "12345", but isn't 12345 without "" is a number ?

Comment: If the data is surrounded with quotes, then its a string.  Similar in concept to thinking that <12345> is a string, and ^123456^ is a string.

Comment: But the OP stated "storing all values in a string array", so OP means the input is in quotes(String). So Hüseyin BABAL's answer which take the input as String is what the OP needs(Even though his answer not shows the parseDouble() ). The checking of "12345" should give the answer "it's an integer". And "12.345" give the answer "it's a double". And "bhusan 123" should give the answer "it's a string"

Comment: is it "123456" or is it "\"123456\"" ?  The data is in a file in ASCII format, so he's reading it like a large string buffer, and he's storing them in a string array because that's the easiest way to store it in memory via string tokenization.   Therefore, if the data in the file is literally \"123456\", then it's not a number.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with simple function;

```
public static boolean isValueInteger(String s) {
    try { 
        Integer.parseInt(s); 
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
        return false;//For example "bhushan" 
    }
    return true;// For example "21" 
}
```

It will throw `NumberFormatException` if it is a `String`

Comment: you can store the value from Integer.parse

Comment: I didn't get you. Why to stroe?

Comment: because if you want to handle string=5 as an int you have to parse it again after your method.
To perform better you can try catch to get the value from the parsing. Why do one action twice?

Comment: You are right, but question owner only asked for only checking variable is int or not.

Comment: Yes I am sorry, I thought that the question was in this way to manipulate string as int after I read "perform some arithmetic operations "

Comment: Throwing exceptions in Java is expensive. Thus, if one expects a lot of String values to not parse correctly it will impact performance

Answer (score 1):

You can try to cast it from string to int.

```
try{
  int result = Integer.parseInt(stringValue);
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
}
```

Comment: You will get `NumberFormatException` on string values like "bhushan". You need to handle that

Answer (score 0):

You usually would use something like regular expression for that. e.g.

```
String number = "daaaa";
Pattern digitPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{6}");       

if (digitPattern.matcher(number).matches()) {
   System.out.println(number + " is a number.");
}
```